# Web Scraping, Serializing and Deserializing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, json

I scraped data from a local .html page and the below code is working. I am a newbie to scraping, just tried with a simple HTML page. It takes 10 sec to complete execution and print data. If I did anything wrong or need improvements, please let me know.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pyodbc
import datetime


class JsonClass:
    def __init__(self, Date, DocumentType, Procedure, NoOfPages):
        self.Date = Date
        self.DocumentType = DocumentType
        self.Procedure = Procedure
        self.NoOfPages = NoOfPages


def json_to_db(json_string):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=xyz-PAVILION;' 'Database=jsondata;' 'Trusted_Connect=yes')
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('EXEC prcJsonInsertData @json = ?',
                   json_string)  # Passing Json Data to DB via Stored Procedure(SP)
        print('Data inserted')
    except pyodbc.Error as error:
        print('Error : %s' % error)
        return False
    except:
        print('Operation Failed')
        return False
    conn.close()
    return True


def json_serialize(dict_list):
    with open('html_to_json.json', 'w') as file_out:
        json.dump(dict_list, file_out, indent=4)  # Serializing dict_list and writing in  .json file
    return json.dumps(dict_list)


def json_deserilaize(json_string):
    with open('html_to_json.json', 'r') as file_out:
    json_data = json.load(file_out)  # Deserialization Data
    json_class = [JsonClass(**i) for i in json_data]  # Binding Json_data to Json_Class
    print('********* After Deserialization *******************')
    print('-------------------------------------')
    for i in json_class:
        print('Date : ' + i.Date)
        print('DocumentType : ' + i.DocumentType)
        print('Procedure : ' + i.Procedure)
        print('NoOfPages : ' + i.NoOfPages)
        print('-------------------------------------')


def html_data():
    my_file = open("C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/sample.htm", 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(my_file, 'html.parser', from_encoding="UTF-8")
    t_body = soup.find('tbody')
    rows = t_body.find_all('tr')
    dict_list = []
    for row in rows:
        column = row.find_all('td')
        column = [x.text for x in column]
        record = dict()
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(column[1], '%d.%m.%Y')
        record['Date'] = date_obj.date().isoformat()
        record['DocumentType'] = column[2]
        record['Procedure'] = column[3].replace('\u00a0/\u00a0', '/').replace('\u00a0', '/')
        record['NoOfPages'] = column[4]
        dict_list.append(record)
    json_string = json_serialize(dict_list)  # Func - 1
    if json_to_db(json_string):  # Func - 2
        json_deserilaize(json_string)  # Func - 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    html_data()
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

### PEP8 names

All of these variables:

```
def __init__(self, Date, DocumentType, Procedure, NoOfPages):
    self.Date = Date
    self.DocumentType = DocumentType
    self.Procedure = Procedure
    self.NoOfPages = NoOfPages
```

should be lower_snake_case.

### Data classes

Replace `JsonClass` with a `@dataclass` that uses an implicit `__init__`.

### Connection

First note that there's no point in separating out your connection parameters like

```
'Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=xyz-PAVILION;'
```

since they will be implicitly concatenated to

```
'Driver={SQL Server};Server=xyz-PAVILION;'
```

Beyond that, the [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/The-pyodbc-Module#connect) states that kwargs are converted to a formatted conn string, so you're better off writing

```
pyodbc.connect(
    Driver='{SQL Server}',
    Server='xyz-PAVILION',
    Database='jsondata',
    Trusted_Connect='yes',
)
```

### Context management

Use a `with` on your connection and cursor objects; read

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#context-manager

### Exception interference

Don't convert exceptions to booleans, as in

```
except pyodbc.Error as error:
    print('Error : %s' % error)
    return False
except:
    print('Operation Failed')
    return False
conn.close()
return True
```

Deal with the exceptions, potentially wrapping them in your own exception types, and catching them at an upper level.

### Double serialization

Don't do this:

```
with open('html_to_json.json', 'w') as file_out:
    json.dump(dict_list, file_out, indent=4)  # Serializing dict_list and writing in  .json file
return json.dumps(dict_list)
```

Hold onto the result of `dumps` and write that string to the file.

### Print helpers

Move this code:

```
    print('Date : ' + i.Date)
    print('DocumentType : ' + i.DocumentType)
    print('Procedure : ' + i.Procedure)
    print('NoOfPages : ' + i.NoOfPages)
```

to a method of `JsonClass`.

### Hard-coded paths

```
my_file = open("C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/sample.htm", 'r')
```

should not be hard-coded. Set it as some kind of parameter - a command-line argument maybe.

### Dict literals

```
    record = dict()
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(column[1], '%d.%m.%Y')
    record['Date'] = date_obj.date().isoformat()
    record['DocumentType'] = column[2]
    record['Procedure'] = column[3].replace('\u00a0/\u00a0', '/').replace('\u00a0', '/')
    record['NoOfPages'] = column[4]
```

should not call `dict()`, should not individually index keys, and should instead use a dict `{}` literal.

Comment: Print Helpers is not working. I created a method def PrintData(i) in JsonClass and using a loop to pass i(parameter to PrintData() method) from the json_desrialisation method.                                                                                             for i in json_class:                                                                                                                                    ....JsonClass.PrintData(i)

Comment: It shouldn't be `def PrintData(i)`; it should be `def print_data(self)`

Comment: I done changes to the above code. Have a look but the helper method is not working(getting a " TypeError: print_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i' ")

Comment: As Mast indicated, you should not be editing this question. If your new solution no longer works, consider posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to get rid of the Unicode [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```
record['Procedure'] = column[3].replace('\u00a0/\u00a0', '/').replace('\u00a0', '/')
```

Dealing with Unicode or character set conversions can be a headache, so I would suggest that you have a look at existing libraries to "normalize" the data. For example: [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)
To convert those non-breaking spaces to regular spaces I would try this:

```
import unicodedata

record['Procedure'] = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", column[3])
```

The benefit would be to "downgrade" a number of pesky characters you may encounter and not just this particular one.

Some background reading: [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)